# Microsoft graph API - Error 307 on update cell

Tags: excel, reactjs, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I need to update a cell content through the microsoft graph API.

I can actually access to my drive, to a file and to a specific cell through `GET /workbook/worksheets/{id|name}/range(address='<address>')`.

Now I need to update the content of a cell (the final behavior is to compute a result thanks to this value and get it in another cell after the **PATCH** request).

But when I call `PATCH /workbook/worksheets/{id|name}/range(address='A1')` with the body

> { values: [[12]] }

to set the value 12 in the cell "A1", I got a 307 HTTP error in response, and then it try to call another URL.

I really don't understand this behavior, because I got it in a Postman, in my react app and in the API tool in microsoft graph site (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#).

The API call is made with axios.

If someone has an idea :)

**UPDATE :** I found the reason of this error. If you try to modify a file, and at the same time the file is open in another tab (or another browser), you have a 307 error. I closed the tab containing the file, and now it works !

Comment: "then it try to call another URL" - and does that succeed? Are you just trying to understand why there is a 307, or is it causing problems?

Comment: No, it does not succeed. I also tried to call a clear, delete, insert but there is the same error... It is causing problem because the sheet is not updated in consequence.